# How to make angular child component stretch css grid column defined in parent component

Tags: javascript, css, angular, css-grid

I have defined the styles of an angular parent component using css grid and want the child component to stretch across the 5 columns. Though other styles are getting applied on the the child component but the child component is not stretching from column 4 till column 99(defined in css file).

Here is the code for parent component

```css
.parent-comp {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

::ng-deep .child-comp {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 9;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-comp">
  <app-child></app-child>
</div>
```

Child component

```html
<p class="child-comp">
  child works!
</p>
```

My understanding is child component should start from column 4 of parent and end at starting line of column 9. But this is not working as my understand. Please help me to understand  my mistake and how can I make it work

[image: Screenshot of child component occupying only first grid]

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vxvhdr)

Comment: Don't you need to add "host"?      host::ng-deep

Comment: @JuanBerzosaTejero already tried it

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the HTML in the browser dev tools you will see that angular inserts a host element for the child component called `<app-child>`.

The HTML will look something like...

```html
<div class="parent-comp">
  <app-child>
    <p class="child-comp">child works!</p>
  </app-child>
</div>
```

You need to target the `app-child` element in your css selector in your parent component's css file...

```css
::ng-deep app-child {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 9;
}
```

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-enagwe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Answer (score 0):

And what about this?:

```
  <app-child class="child-comp"></app-child>
```

It works for you?

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-avijo8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html